# Using underscores in classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class

I've read that the underscore in js is an acceptable naming character with no additional functionality, used to signify something is private. My question is how does this work then?

```js
class User {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name
    }

    set name(value) {
        if (value.length < 4) {
            alert("Name is too short")
            return
        }
        this._name = value
    }
}

let user = new User("Kiki")
alert(user.name)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

The variable is not defined the first time with the underscore, how does JavaScript know what I'm referring to?

Also if I remove the underscores I get an error that

> InternalError: too much recursion

I don't understand why? If the underscore has no functionality, shouldn't it work the same without the underscores?

Comment: There is a recursion because the setter has the same name as the property you are changing if you remove the underscore, it creates an infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working version has **two** properties:

- `_name`, a data property you create in the constructor
- `name`, an [*accessor* property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) you create on the class prototype via `get name() { /*...*/ }` (and `set name(value) { /*...*/ }`)

In this code:

```
let user = new User("Kiki")
alert(user.name)
```

...when you use `user.name`, you're using the *accessor* property's getter function (`get name`), which returns the value of `this._name`.

If you remove the `_`, you have only **one** property, which is the accessor property, and assigning to `this.name` in the constructor calls the accessor's setter function, which (in that version) would do `this.name = ____`, which would call the setter function, which would do `this.name = ____`, which would call the setter function...

If you're going to have that public `name` property that does validation on the value you assign to it, you need a place to keep the value the accessor accesses. That can be another public property with a different name (`_name`), which is fine though easily bypassed; or in modern code you might use a [private instance field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_fields) instead:

```js
class User {
    #name; // Private instance field declaration

    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    get name() {
        return this.#name;
    }

    set name(value) {
        if (value.length < 4) {
            console.log("Name is too short");
            return;
        }
        this.#name = value;
    }
}

let user = new User("Kiki");
console.log(user.name);
```

Side note: I'd make the error condition throw an `Error`, not just output a message, not least so that `new User("x")` doesn't leave the name with the default value `undefined`:

```js
set name(value) {
    if (value.length < 4) {
        throw new Error(`Name is too short, expected at least 4 chars, got ${value.length}`);
    }
    this.#name = value;
}
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> ...if I put `this._name=name` in the constructor it works as well. Would that be better practice?

That would mean that you wouldn't check the length of the name passed to the constructor. But your instinct is good! In class-based OOP circles, best practice is usually not to call setters (or other public methods) from constructors, because the setter/method may be overridden in a derived class, and the derived class may expect that the setter is working with a fully-initialized instance. But when you all a setter from the constructor, the instance may not be fully initialized yet.

In your specific case it doesn't really matter, there's only one property (conceptually), but the usual way to avoid the issue with overridden setters/methods is to use a private function that does the work of the setter, and use that function both in the setter and the constructor:

```js
class User {
    #name;

    constructor(name) {
        this.#setName(name);
    }

    #setName(value) { // <== Private instance method
        if (value.length < 4) {
            throw new Error(`Name is too short, expected at least 4 chars, got ${value.length}`);
        }
        this.#name = value;
    }

    get name() {
        return this.#name;
    }

    set name(value) {
        this.#setName(value);
    }
}

try {
    let user = new User("Kiki");
    console.log(user.name);
} catch (error) {
    console.error("ERROR, the first call should work");
}

try {
    let user = new User("X");
    console.log(user.name);
    console.error("ERROR, the second call should fail");
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`Second call failed as expected: ${error.message}`);
}


try {
    let user = new User("Kiki");
    console.log(user.name);
    user.name = "x";
    console.error("ERROR, the third call should fail");
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`Third call failed as expected: ${error.message}`);
}
```

Since a private method *can't* be overridden in a derived class, it's okay to call it from the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for writing a very concise answer. It's a bit more clear now. But what I still don't get is, in the constructor I set this.name = name, but the getter and setter are getting the _name for the first time. How do those methods know what I'm refering to? Also if I put this._name=name in the constructor it works aswell. Would that be better practice?

Comment: @sljafna - When you do `this.name = name` in the constructor, you call the setter method, which sets `this._name` (after checking the length). *"Also if I put this._name=name in the constructor it works aswell. Would that be better practice?"* That's a very good instinct. You wouldn't want to do that exactly, but the instinct not to call the public setter is a good one. I've added to the end of the answer to explain.

Comment: I still dont get it completely but you've made it way more clear for me. I feel like you've given me all the information to understand it completely, at least for my level of knowledge, so I thank you for taking your time and helping me out :)

Comment: @sljafna - My pleasure. Happy coding! You're on the right track! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The underscore is just a commonly-used way of remembering that the property is private. You can use any variable name you want.

Just remember that there are *two* identifiers for the `name`, one is for internal use and one is for external use. They can't be exactly the same.

```
class User {
    constructor(name) {
        this.privateName = name
    }

    get name() {
        return this.privateName
    }

    set name(value) {
        if (value.length < 4) {
            alert("Name is too short")
            return
        }
        this.privateName = value
    }
}

let user = new User("Kiki")
console.log(user.name)
```

That being said, in the latest javascript you can (should?) use the # to make private properties. This makes sure they are actually private (not reachable from outside the class)

```
class User {

  #name

  constructor(name) {
    this.#name = name
  }

  get name() {
    return this.#name
  }

  set name(value) {
    if (value.length < 4) {
      alert("Name is too short")
      return
    }
    this.#name = value
  }
}

let user = new User("Henk")
console.log(user.name)
```

And because we used `#` the private variable actually can't be reached:

```
 console.log(user.#name) // ERROR
```

Comment: But in the first example, in the constructor you set this.privateName=name, so it makes sense to me that you used that privateName in the getter and setter. However if the constructor is this.name =name. And I use the privateName for getter and setter, it still works. I dont understand how do the get and set know what I'm refering to with privateName

Comment: The identifier you use after `get` and `set` has to be different from the internal variable name. So for example `get coolName` and `this.myName` would also work. Just think of them as two separate things, one is for internal use and the other is for external use. You connect them by doing `set coolName(value) {this.myName = value}` and `get coolName {return this.myName}`